# Sqlite3 deadlock with concurrent db updates, VB .net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, concurrency, deadlock

My program consists of many classes which run their own update function to check an sqlite database and update if a change is found.

```
Async Function update() As Task(Of String)
.
.
  Await Task.Run(Sub()
    .
    .                          
  End Sub)
.
.
  helper.updatedb(par1, par2, par3, par4)
.
.
End Function

Sub updatedb(ByVal name As String, ByVal entry As String, ByVal smth As String, Optional ByVal random As String = vbNullString)

            Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
            Dim SQLcommand As SQLiteCommand
            SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "data source=" + dbpath
            SQLconnect.Open()
            SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
            SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT ""entry"" FROM profiles WHERE ""name"" = @name"
            SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", LCase(name))
            Dim SQLreader As SQLiteDataReader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()
            SQLreader.Read()

            Dim result As String = SQLreader(0)

                SQLcommand.Dispose()
                SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
                SQLcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE profiles SET ""entry"" = @entry WHERE ""name"" = @name"
                SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", LCase(name))
                SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entry", entry)

                SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            SQLcommand.Dispose()
            SQLreader.Close()
            SQLconnect.Close()
            SQLconnect.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

The problem appears when SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery is executed while possibly another thread has writing access to the db. "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll".

I read in some other thread that this could be countered using mutex on the update command. How would I go about implementing mutex to my code? Is there some sqlite alternative which favors portability and has no such concurrency issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'll be damned... Seems the problem was the placing of the dispose statements:

```
Dim SQLreader As SQLiteDataReader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()
->SQLcommand.Dispose()
SQLreader.Read()

Dim result As String = SQLreader(0)
->SQLreader.Close()
```

Now it works as intended...

Answer (score 0):

See [this online help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

You create lock variable, and then lock it; only one thread can have the lock at one time, and others automatically wait:

```
Dim lockThis As New Object

Sub updatedb(ByVal name As String, ...)
    SyncLock lockThis
        Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
        ...
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same "database is locked" error.